# Inno Setup Hindi language file not working

Tags: unicode, inno-setup

I am using the Unicode version of the Inno Setup. I am using Hindi as a language. I have download the `Hindi.islu` from:

https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Files/Languages/Unofficial/Hindi.islu

There was no problem in compilation and packaging. When I try to run the setup after selecting the Hindi language, the next screen shows only gibberish.

What do you think? What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Hindi.islu` is missing UTF-8 [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Just add it and the translation will work correctly.

*An easy way to add the UTF-8 byte order mark is by opening the file in Windows Notepad and saving it without any change.*

[image: Hindi Inno Setup]

---

I have posted a bug report (it was removed meanwhile, without fixing).

Comment: Thank you very much. That works! Good to know about the reporting of the bug.